# What specific advantages are there for writing the melody first vs the harmony first?

Tags: chord-progressions

In what instances would it be beneficial to choose to write the melody first or the harmony first? Are there any examples in history of a composer / songwriter favoring one method over the other? If so, what impact did it have on the character of their music?

Comment: If my math are correct there are two questions here which are not completely equivalent. Especially the one in the text sounds very opinion based, but maybe that's me...

Comment: Different composers had different approaches, all of which led to results that have stood the test of time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is fundamentally unanswerable. Composers have created music by every means available, and no composer has composed in only one way. All of the composers whose music has stood the test of time achieved superb results regardless the process.

Comment: It is possible to write both at the same time. At least some modern composers go measure by measure or page by page.

Comment: Which is better - chalk or cheese?

Comment: You cannot write a melody without a chord progression, they go hand-in-hand. It is like trying to build a house without a house-plan!

Comment: I actually disagree. When writing counterpoint, for example, you usually start with the melody only and fill in the rest as you go.

Comment: Bach had a long history of taking old religious music with a modal melody (often sung in unison or parallel intervals), and completely changing their nature by writing new counterpoint lines and giving the melody a new harmonic context.

Comment: Nice edit but it is still asking too many questions, opinionated, discussion-provoking questions at that - "what impact did it have on the character of their music?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of question is a false dilemma: it assumes one or the other is true.  But the fact is that a good composer will often be thinking about both melodic ideas and harmonic motion together.

The other problem is that you think this is a conscious, logical process.  Sometimes it is, and sometimes it isn't.  Normally, when I'm composing, I'll improvise harmony and melody together on the piano, and then I'll "feel" where some part of the thing wants to go-- it can be harmonic, melodic, some orchestral texture, pretty much anything.

This is me at random points in the process:

- Oooh, that chord wants to go minor next.  How can I leap to that
  flattened third in the melody?
- That word needs to really punch.  What nasty chord should I throw in under this note to show I mean business?
- This sounds cool, but it really feels like it should be brass and
  maybe timpani.  What octave would really hit the trumpets' power zone?

Or, maybe **once or twice a year** (and that might be a bit generous), on waking up in a cold sweat:
"Wait. . . what is that?  I don't think that's even a song yet.  I have to write it down-- **dammit where's my pencil?**"  and I write down a full melody and chords, never having thought about their composition at all.

*(My three favorite things I've written came that way-- and I had to ask composer friends to check if it was just an accidental plagiarism, but it never was, at least that we could figure out)*

Comment: A false dilemma is also called a false dichotomy

Comment: Yeah, it's only a dilemma if you're agonizing over choosing one or the other. :D

Answer (score 2):

It is quite hard, in my opinion, to determine which approach is better. One might find it easier to write a melody over a given chord progression, another one the other way around.

For me in a Jazz context, it is often more fun to sit at the piano, come up with a chord progression and then write a melody. A friend of mine goes the other way around and first writes the melody and after that the chord progression.

Now consider a polyphonic piece of music, like a fugue or a canon. I would argue that the melodic idea and the melodic material determines the harmony of the piece and the melody has to fit some specific needs for your piece. (Dissonance with the counterpoint or Dux and Comes.

These are just a few examples on how different people might need different approaches to write music. As Aaron in the comments wrote: "It is an unanswerable question." And I would add that it depends on your personal preference.